# Splunk ODBC error using Tableau or Power BI

Tags: powerbi, splunk, tableau-desktop

In Power BI, I am seeing the saved searches from splunk, and trying to connect to a saved search that is very small, i.e, 4 columns and 8 rows.  Power BI tries to load the data for 2 minutes but then fails saying SPLUNKODBC (40) Error with HTTP API, error code:Failed writing received data to disk/application.  I tried doi.this in Tableau and have the same problem -   I've seen a few postings on this but no solutions other than people referring to a solution provided by a splunk employee, but that doesn't help.  Any ideas?